# python open first row in csv then save the remaining rows only in the same csv file

Tags: python, csv

What is the most efficient way?

Number of rows is approximately 100,000. So using a standard for loop to read all line and the using for loop to write the remaining lines must be very inefficient.

Comment: Are you reading the line from a file?

Comment: please provide your example

Comment: It sounds like you want to update the `.csv` file in place. That is not how textfiles work. If you use one `for` loop to read all the lines into memory and another to write them all out again (except for one) that *will* be inefficient because it will read your whole file into memory. But you can read one file and write another in the same loop.

Comment: it is a csv file

Comment: so there is no efficient way with csv files(text files). I guess this is why I need to use a database when the size of data becomes too large?